# Eric6 on Ubuntu No module named 'serial'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am testing Eric6 IDE in Ubuntu and copy paste a code snippet to get a list of serial ports.
Although I installed pyserial by "python3 -m pip install pyserial",the Eric IDE keeps producing this error.
Running the code in the terminal does work (no error message, but also no list of ports yet...)

Answer (score 0):

As the [pyserial docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) suggest, the package you want actually might be named differently.

> Packages There are also packaged versions for some Linux
> distributions:
>
> Debian/Ubuntu: “python-serial”, “python3-serial” Fedora / RHEL /
> CentOS / EPEL: “pyserial” Arch Linux: “python-pyserial” Gentoo:
> “dev-python/pyserial”

Maybe this helps? I had a similar issue with using pyserial with Scripts run on both Windows and Ubuntu machines.